# vagrantfileにインストールOSを指定することは可能なのでしょうか？

Tags: vagrant

プログラミングスクールでvagrantfileをもらってそれを使いたいフォルダに移動し`vagrant up`でするだけでubuntu14.04を自動でインストールするようになっているのですが`add box`を行っていないのにいきなりubuntu14.04が起動するのですがそのようなことは可能なのでしょうか？
Vagrantfileを見ても特に記述してなく書いてあると言えば`config.vm.box = ubuntu/trusty32`くらいです。

どなたか詳しい方教えて頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`config.vm.box` の部分でまさに OS を指定しています。

Ubuntu にはコードネームといって、各リリースに対してバージョン番号とは別に名前が振り分けられています。Ubuntu Trusty Tahr とは Ubuntu 14.04 LTS のことです。[Wikipedia の Ubuntu のページ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu#%E3%83%AA%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7)などに一覧が載っています。

`config.vm.box` には、既にインストールされている box の名前か、[Vagrant Cloud](https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search) にアップロードされている box の名前を指定します（[ドキュメント](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/machine_settings.html)にそう書いてあります）。今回の場合 `config.vm.box = ubuntu/trusty32` なので、Vagrant Cloud にアップロードされている https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty32 が指定されていることになり、したがって 32 bit 版 Ubuntu 14.04 の box が使われます。他にたとえば `config.vm.box = centos/7` とすると、 https://app.vagrantup.com/centos/boxes/7 が指定されることになり CentOS 7 の box が使われます。

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。ただ一体どこからDLしているのでしょうか？名前を宣言しているだけのように見えるのですが

Comment: config.vm.box_url というのを使うとローカル環境にOSがない時にダウンロードしてくれるみたいなことが書いてあるのですが、僕が使っているVagrantfileには書いてありませんでした。

Comment: @wataru 回答に追記しました。ご確認ください。

Comment: 丁寧にありがとうございました。